# Google Sheet + Script + Textfinder + Check

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm using this code to get a list of rows that matches the searchtext from column "A" and that works great .
But what I'm trying to do is insert a checkmark in column C for each row that match
So basically how would I use the array from .map((r) => r.offset(0,3).getA1Notation()) to insert a checkmark on those rows in column "C"

Thanks

```
function check(){
  var rangeList = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange('A2:A');
  var searchText = "dog";
  .createTextFinder(searchText)
  .matchEntireCell(true)
  .findAll()
  .map((r) => r.offset(0,3).getA1Notation())
  
   console.log(rangeList);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Insert Checkboxes

```
function check(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const searchText = "dog";
  const rangeList = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).createTextFinder(searchText).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().map((r) => r.offset(0,3).insertCheckboxes());   
}
```

Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks cooper this one also works great

Answer (score 1):

From `how would I use the array from .map((r) => r.offset(0,3).getA1Notation()) to insert a checkmark on those rows in column "C"`, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function check() {
  var searchText = "dog";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var rangeList = sheet
    .getRange('A2:A')
    .createTextFinder(searchText)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findAll()
    .map((r) => r.offset(0, 2).getA1Notation());
  sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).insertCheckboxes().check(); // or sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).insertCheckboxes();
  console.log(rangeList);
}
```

- I think that `.createTextFinder(searchText).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().map((r) => r.offset(0,3).getA1Notation())` occurs an error.
- In the case of `.map((r) => r.offset(0, 3).getA1Notation())`, an array including A1Notation is returned. You can use this for achieving your goal.
- When you want to put the checkbox to the column "C", please modify `r.offset(0,3).getA1Notation()` to `r.offset(0, 2).getA1Notation()`.
- If you don't want to insert the checked checkboxes, please remove `.check()`.

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike works great as usual

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.